# "Truth needs to be told/said/spoken."

Tags: difference, verbs

Which one of these is correct?

> •Truth needs to be **told**.
> •Truth needs to be **said**.
> •Truth needs to be **spoken**.

These are my guess:
**'spoken'** is a past participle and there's no had/have in the sentence so, I don't think **'spoken'** can be used. Or if it can be used, then by which rule? What would be its tense?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the basic structure of all three as the same:

- *need* + infinitive

As in:

- I need to go
- He needs to say [something]
- We need to speak

Those examples all use the active infinitive. Yours use passive infinitives. That's the only difference.

- I want to annoy [infinitive]
- I want to be annoyed [passive infinitive]

I hope you can see that **grammatically**, your three options are all fine. However, in terms of common phrases, *tell the truth* is the clear winner---it's by far the most common phrase. *Say the truth* is not used in English, and *speak the truth* is used, but not as frequently.

So this question has nothing to do with grammar, just common phrasing. And *the truth needs to be told* is the natural-sounding, common phrasing.

---

Note: Not every grammarian likes the term *passive infinitive*, or even *infinitive*, when talking about English. I have used it here for simplicity.